# How to expand collapse reviews

Tags: jquery

I have some reviews for products, i want to show the reviewers name but then if the user clicks the name, the whole review expands.

This is how ive tried doing it

This is a snippet from my page

```
"<article class='reviews'>";
  $q = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT *FROM reviews WHERE product_id = '$pid' AND status = 
  '1' ORDER BY id DESC ");
  if (!mysqli_num_rows($q)){
    echo"There Are No Reviews For This Product Yet";}
  else{
    echo"<article class='reviewslatest'>",
  "<article class='reviewslatestheading'>Latest Customer Review</article>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "<article class='reviewsuser'>Review By - {$row['name']}</article>";
    echo "<article class='reviewsinfo'>",
    nl2br ($row['info']),
    "</article>";}}
  echo"</article>",
"</article>";
```

And this is the jquery ive been trying to use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".reviewsuser").click(function () {
  $header = $(this);
  $content = $header.next();
  $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
  $header.text(function () {
  return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
});
});
});
});
```

At the minute this does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a start for you to consider - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/fm1tgr49/).

Your question contains the php code you use to move data from your db to your client, but I would suggest that you focus just on the structure of the DOM.

So my fiddle used your php code to "create" a theoretical DOM (I hope it looks like you want it to), then I just styled it and added a simple jQuery command.

The JS won't work perfectly for long page of reviews, but could be modified based on how you visualize the DOM.

JS

```
$('.reviewsuser').on('click', function(){
        $('.reviewsinfo').slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

---

edit: Put these lines in your header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

---

Comment: your fiddle is exactly what im after but it doesnt work for me! any ideas why this would be so?

Comment: Do you mean the fiddle doesn't work? Or the code doesn't work in your page?

Comment: sorry, i mean the code doesn't work on my page. the fiddle works perfectly

Comment: So you need to make sure you've included jQuery in your header (see my edited answer), then do a "view source" on your webpage to see if the classes/divs/etc are all labeled correctly.

Comment: This is a weird one, I have included jquery. But I used your lines to see if it made any difference. It still doesnt work! View page source confirmed that all the classes match too! Any ideas why it wouldnt be working?

Comment: Scrub that, got it working. I took out some other jquery plugins and it worked!

Comment: I'm sure Thoreau was thinking about jQuery when he said "Simplify, simplify".